# How to extract all different tags from one column?

Tags: mysql

Considering the data-table as below:

| tags |
| --- |
| alpha |
| alpha, beta |
| delta |
| beta, gamma |

How can get all different tags in one query? So the expected result should be:

**alpha**
**beta**
**gamma**
**delta**

(order is not important)

I have been thinking a lot, but could not find out the solution. :)

Comment: How many CSV tags can appear in a given row?

Comment: 2 or 3 tags. But I think if there is a solution, then that solution would work for any number of tags. :)

Comment: Please see the answers to the following question before you proceed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1):

We get all tags splited by ',' then we use `union` to keeps unique records only :

```
select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 1))
from tags
union 
select TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', -1))
from tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there would be a max of 3 CSV words per record *and* that you are using MySQL 8+, we can try using a regex substring approach:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT tags
FROM
(
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, '\\w+', 1, 1) AS tags FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, '\\w+', 1, 2) FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, '\\w+', 1, 3) FROM yourTable
) t;
```